# Validar unión de varios campos en un modelo en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo donde almaceno los datos de las facturas de compras: Proveedor, tipo_comprobante, letra_comprobante, sucursal y numero_comprobante. Lo que necesito es que al ingresar un nuevo comprobante, validar que no se repita. Es decir que no se cargue dos veces la misma factura de compra.

```
class FactProv(models.Model):
    ''' Esta tabla almacena todos los detalles de la factura de compra '''
    letra_comprobante = models.CharField(max_length= 1, choices=Letra.choices, default= 
                        Letra.A, verbose_name= 'Letra')
    sucursal = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 4, decimal_places=0, 
               verbose_name='Sucursal')
    numero_comprobante = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, verbose_name 
                       = 'Numero')
    tipo_comprobante = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name= 'Tipo Comprobante', 
                       choices= Tipo.choices, default=Tipo.FC)
    proveedores = models.ForeignKey(Proveedores, default = None, on_delete= 
                  models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

Algo que se me ocurre es en mi vista validar campo por campo si existe el dato, por ejemplo el campo 'numero_comprobante':

```
nro_compr = form['numero_comprobante'].value()
if self.model.objects.filter(numero_comprobante = nro_compr).exists():
   print("Existe el numero de comprobante")
else:
   print('No existe el numero de comprobante')
```

> Hice un resumen del código para no hacerlo muy extenso.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega `unique=True` a tu campo.

```
numero_comprobante = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, verbose_name='Numero', unique=True)
```

o puedes hacerlo en el método `save`:

```
class FactProv(models.Model):

    # defines todos tus campos y otros métodos

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False): 
        if not FactProv.objects.filter(numero_comprobante=self.numero_comprobante).exists(): 
            super(FactProv, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

### Update 1

En base a lo que comentas, si quieres que se aplique una validacion de multiples campos unicos puedes utilizar `UniqueConstraint`

```
class FactProv(models.Model):

    # defines todos tus campos y otros métodos

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['numero_comprobante', 'proveedores'], name='unico comprobante por proveedor')
        ]
```

### Update 2

También puedes hacerlo sobrescribiendo el método `clean`.
Esta función se ejecuta antes de las operación de guardar o actualizar un registro en la base de datos:

```
class FactProv(models.Model):
    ## Defines tus campos y demas métodos

    def clean(self):
        if FactProv.objects.filter(numero_comprobante=self.numero_comprobante, proveedores=self.proveedores).exists():
            raise ValidationError('EL numero de comprobante ya existe para este proveedor')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo de unique=True lo pense, pero para mi caso no funcionaria, ya que puede haber el mismo numero de comprobante pero de distinto proveedor. Lo que si puede funcionar es utilizando el metodo save y haciendo if anidados por cada campo. Lo que no entiendo es lo de force_insert=False y force_update=False.

Comment: Los parámetros `force_insert` te permite forzar una inserción a la base de datos en lugar de hacer un update de un campo y el parámetro `force_update` te permite actualizar de manera forzosa un registro de la base de datos. 
Te dejo por acá la documentación para que la revises https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.1/ref/models/instances/#ref-models-force-insert

Comment: Ok. Muhisimas gracias. Otra manera que se me ocurre seria anular el metodo clean del ModelForm. Podria funcionar?

Comment: Lo que estuve leyendo es que UniqueConstraint se valida a nivel de Base de Datos, por lo que no es posible (o al menos yo no lo veo posible) hacer excepciones.